# Missing DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock in OpenID+OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am implementing OpenID+OAuth in my ASP.NET WebForm (using .NET Framework 3.5) application, found example on net

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/dotnetopenid/xQYkE6sUZYU
```

But I am missing DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock namespace, I included these libraries in my project:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.dll
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client.dll
```

Can any one suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

The ApplicationBlock is not distributed in binary form as it is intended for copy+paste of relevant source code into your project.  You can get the ApplicationBlock project from the samples distribution on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dnoa/files/latest/).

Comment: I think you should have ApplicationBlock as an optional download on nuget. It would make it much easier and hassle free.

Comment: The latest project is now on github - https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth. Official website is http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the project under the DotNotOpenAuth folders at Samples/DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock